# How to rebase when it says that current branch is up to date even though it isn't?

Tags: git, rebase

I rebased my branch which had the effect of putting some commits on top of my own. Then realized I had forgotten to squash some commits, so hard reset and squashed. Now I need to bring those commits back. But rebasing again tells me that the current branch is up to date, even though it isn't. Is there a way to fix this?

Edit:

There are two branches: a and b. Both are branched from master. Both are up to date with master. Branch a has some changes. I want branch b to have those changes too. I rebased branch a on to b. The latest commit was from branch a. I meant to squash the three commits before that commit. I hard reset to before the latest commit. Then I squashed. Now I want to get back that latest commit in a way that won't cause headaches when the time comes to merge branch b to master.

I've tried `reflog` and `git reset --hard HEAD@{n}` but same problem: Current branch is up to date.

Comment: "I rebased my branch which had the effect of putting some commits on top of my own." Not the other way around (put your commits on top of those of the branch onto which you rebased)?

Comment: "so hard reset" hard reset which branch to what revision?

Comment: [Undo your bad rebase](http://stackoverflow.com/q/134882/6194839) then [Rebase Properly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7929369/6194839)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do you use git rebase instead of git merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/when-do-you-use-git-rebase-instead-of-git-merge)

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893399/rebase-feature-branch-onto-another-feature-branch) would be helpful to understand how re basing works

Answer (score 6):

In my case `--force-rebase` helped. I guess, in your case it would be:

```
git checkout b
git rebase --force-rebase a
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the issue was simply that master was outdated compared to origin/master, so I had to run:

```bash
git branch -f master origin/master
```

Answer (score 2):

It's proppably because u haven't pull changes to local on branch master. Try this:

1. Commit all changes on your current branch.
2. Switch to master `git checkout master`.
3. Pull changes `git pull`.
4. Switch to "current" branch `git checkout {current}`.
5. Try `Git rebase master`.

Comment: Hi @Mateusz, The OP asked about local branches. How would your answer look like with local branches?

Answer (score 0):

In case you have your commit's id, you can use the interactive rebase and add them manually.

Assuming your origin branch was `master`, you can do:

```sh
git rebase -i master
```

And you will receive something like this:

```sh
pick 000000 Name of a commit
pick 000001 Name of another commit
```

You can add another `pick bbbbbb` with the commitId you want to add, something like

```sh
pick 000000 Name of a commit
pick bbbbbb
pick 000001 Name of another commit
```

If you want to squash a commit, you can do:

```sh
pick 000000 Name of a commit
squash bbbbbb
pick 000001 Name of another commit
```

The squash operation will append your lower commit to the previous one, that means the `00000`

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't push that rebase, you can reset hard to the remote repository branch.

```sh
git reset --hard origin/your-branch-name
```

Comment: Don’t answer the same question multiple times please.

Comment: @matt they are different options, not a duplication.