# Git pull before rebasing

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull

So I [asked a question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40009820/4114128) about rebasing in git and got some good answers on what to do. However When I proceeded, I ran into issues that I dont understand 1 bit.

To give a quick overview:

I branched out (`Branch2`) from another branch - `Branch1`. `Branch1` is remote and had a number of commits AFTER I branched from it. All those commits are not squashed. Meanwhile I went about making changes in `Branch2`. Now Im done with my changes and have to rebase `Branch2` on top of `Branch1`.

When I do `git status` in `Branch2` it lists all the files that I have changed (which seems right). However when I do a `git checkout Branch1` and the `git status` it lists the same files again. I dont understand this, I was under the impression that each branch is like a localized environment and does not show changes to other branches.

Another thing that has my head spinning is that - `Branch1` has moved forward since I branched out from it. Before rebasing I wanted to update my local copy of `Branch1` so that my changes in `Branch2` get rebased on top of the the most recent commits of `Branch1` so I did `git checkout Branch1` and `git pull`. However I got :

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    file...
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

I dont understand:

1. Why are changes done in `branch2` showing in `git status` of `Branch1`?
2. If I commit and push my changes on `Branch1`, then `git pull`, where will my commit be placed as all the previous commits including the commit where I had branched of of in `Branch1` have been squashed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I do git status in `Branch2` it lists all the files that I have changed (which seems right).

A branch is a pointer to a commit. `git status` shows the files that are modified but not committed. Maybe it seems right to you but until you commit the changes, checking out a different branch is a risky operation.

> However when I do a `git checkout Branch1` and the `git status` it lists the same files again.

This is because the uncommitted changes are not in a branch and that means they are not in the repository. They are only in the working tree.

> I dont understand this, I was under the impression that each branch is like a localized environment and does not show changes to other branches.

Your impression is correct.

> Another thing that has my head spinning is that - `Branch1` has moved forward since I branched out from it.

Since you didn't create any commit in `Branch2`, you technically didn't "branched out" from it. `Branch2` is just a commit in the past of `Branch1` and not a real branch. Commit your changes on `Branch2` and it will branch out.

> However I got :
>
> ```
> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
>    file...
> Please, commit your changes or stash
> ```

Well, `git` is trying hard to not destroy your work. It suggests you what to do in order to be safe.

---

If I understood correctly your desire, the commands you have to run are as follows:

```
# go back to Branch2
git checkout Branch2

# commit the changes in Branch2
git add .
git commit

# get the recent commits on Branch1 from the remote server
# there is no need to merge them
git fetch origin

# rebase Branch1 on top of the remote version of Branch1
# git pull produces the same result if you didn't commit anything on Branch1
git rebase origin/Branch1 Branch1

# rebase the commit(s) you created in Branch2 on top of Branch1
git rebase origin/Branch1 Branch2

# now you are on Branch2 and Branch1 is in the past of Branch2
```

Good luck!

Comment: So I commited my files from `Branch2`. Now I switched over to `Branch1` and did `git fetch origin`. However `git log` shows the `HEAD` is still at an older commit (which no longer exists)

Comment: `git fetch` doesn't change the current branch. In fact, it doesn't change anything regarding the local repo. I just gets from the remote repo the commits that are not present in the local repo. It also updates the information it caches about the branches of the remote repo. `git pull` does `git fetch` followed by `git merge` (or `git rebase` if the `--rebase` option is present in its command line). `git merge` and `git rebase` are the ones that change the local repo.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are failing to commit your `branch2` before switching back to `branch1`. You will carry all of your uncommitted data back to the previous branch. You have a couple of options: either `commit` first, run `git checkout .` to undo them, or run `git stash` before switching.