# Git - Created a branch from previous release branch and want to copy changes to current release branch

Tags: git, merge, copy, rebase

Working on a feature branch that was created from a previous release branch. The feature could not be merged into that release. Now I want to merge this feature branch into the current release branch. How do I copy all my changes (100 of files) from feature branch to current release branch.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893399/rebase-feature-branch-onto-another-feature-branch/14893561

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`git rebase --onto`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase---ontoltnewbasegt):

```
git rebase --onto newReleaseBranch $(git merge-base oldReleaseBranch featureBranch) featureBranch
```

It uses [`git merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) to compute the base commit between the `oldReleaseBranch` and your feature branch.