# git - develop base and extended feature - commits in base should reflect in extended in pull

Tags: git, github, version-control, development-environment

Hie I am working around in git to achieve something like mentioned below.

Imagine there is a Big feature which is going to develop - since it's very big they have split into core feature and an extended feature.

Now they have divided into teams for development.

Now how to make branches in a below-mentioned way

the core will be developing in core_branch
extended will be developing in extended_branch containing core develpment
it should be like that when we perform git pull in extended_branch it has to pull if any commits made to core_branch how to achieve this??

I am aware of git rebase / git merge. In either of the cases, extended team/developers have to check any new commits in the core branch and merge/rebase their extended_branch

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

(1) Set up the `core_branch`.

```
git checkout -b core_branch
```

You can develop and push to `core_branch` as normal

(2) Check out a branch for `extended_branch` based off of `core_branch`.

```
git checkout -b extended_branch # be sure to do this while on core_branch
```

(3) When on `extended_branch`, if you want to pull in changes from `core_branch`, then do the following

```
git fetch origin core_branch
git rebase -i core_branch # do this while on extended_branch
```

After this step, all the commits to `core_branch` will be on extended_branch.

Comment: My answer is also expressed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893399/rebase-feature-branch-onto-another-feature-branch

Comment: here you are manually checking every time core_branch is updated. the point is you won't be knowing when core branch gets updated

Comment: i don't believe there's a way to get an automatic update. Just as you need to pull master manually, you'll need to pull/rebase off core_branch manually