# How to get changes from branch that is checkout from another branch?

Tags: git

I have checked out branch B from A. And I have made some fixes in branch A. Afterwards I am going merge B into A. but right now I want changes from branch A to branch B which are made after checkout.

Comment: rebasing should cover what you need to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893399/rebase-feature-branch-onto-another-feature-branch

Comment: What does "checked out branch B from A" mean? You created branch B on top of branch A and then checked that out?

Comment: `git rebase` B on top of the latest A should work.

Comment: Merging a into b should also work.

Comment: @WernerHenze yes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of cherry picking
use git log to check all new commits in A
apply all commits one by one to branch B

```
git cherry pick A11 // assume A1 is the commits , do this in branch B
```

Make sure your sequence is right i.e oldest to newest from all new commits

Comment: This will only cherry-pick *one* commit. What if changes in `A` consist of several commits? `git cherry-pick B..A` would cover that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many ways.You can use **git merge** or **git rebase**.
Assuming you are in branch A right now

> Using merge:

```
git checkout B
git merge A // (there won't be any conflicts now)
```

> Or you can do this simply by git rebase:

```
git rebase A B // (there won't be any conflicts now)
```