# Rebase feature branch onto another feature branch with revert commit

Tags: git, rebase

My question is similar to [Rebase feature branch onto another feature branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893399/rebase-feature-branch-onto-another-feature-branch)

While working on a feature, we mistakenly made a commit in "Feature 1" branch `Commit C` which was reverted and create a branch for the sub-feature and cherry picked the commit.

```
A - B - C - C"(Revert C) - D    -- Feature-1
     \ 
      C'(Cherry Pick C) - E - F - G   -- Branch-1
```

Now few bug fixes were merged onto Feature 1 which are needed for my branch to pass the tests. Hence I want to rebase Branch 1 so that it looks like

```
A - B - C - C"(Revert C) - D    -- Feature-1
                            \ 
                             C'(Cherry Pick C) - E - F - G   -- Branch-1
```

I tried to rebase the using `(On Branch-1)$ git rebase Feature-1` but this did not pick the commit `C'` as it finds it is already present in the branch.
How should I do the rebase ?

Comment: Do you like to remove C'? Or C, or both?

Comment: @Julian: Not remove C' but keep it. So when rebasing it finds C' commit is already present in path as commit C. Hence after rebase the C' commit does not get picked. Hence the Branch-1 looks like `<previous> - D - E - F - G`

Comment: Clear. I think you could cherry pick C again

Comment: In the first commit graph. Are you sure it is C' and not just C?

Any reason not to reorder both branches and don't do a revert on C in Feature 1?

Comment: @BlackEye: `C'` is exactly same as `C`, only it is cherry picked onto a different branch. How can I reorder both branches ? Problem was we realized very late that commit C was added onto feature branch

Comment: @Pratham you can do a rebase on any commit, so you can also can do a rebase an commit B or C for both branches and just remove commits C and C'' for feature-1 for example.

Comment: @BlackEye : Correct, but other dev's working on the branch would have to force pull the branch as it will not be a fast forward. Hence looking for a non intrusive solution.

Comment: It's a feature branch, we prefer a clear and non hazardous feature branch over a non "intrusive" one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the commits in the same order, you could `checkout` commit `D`, `cherry-pick` commit `C`, then jump back to `Branch-1` and `rebase` on top of the newly `cherry-picked` commit `C`.  There very well may be a more efficient method, but this is **one way**.

1. `git checkout <hash of D>`
2. `git cherry-pick <hash of C>`
3. `git checkout Branch-1`
4. `git rebase <hash of newly cherry-picked C>`

The interim tree between steps `2` and `4` would look like this.

```
                             C'''(Cherry Pick C) (rebase on this)
                            /
A - B - C - C"(Revert C) - D    -- Feature-1
                            \ 
                             C'(Cherry Pick C) - E - F - G   -- Branch-1
```

You could also create temporary branches instead of using hashes, if that is easier to think about.